Almost everywhere convergence vs convergence in measure
On the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), m)$
, here $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Consider $f_n(x) = n(1 - nx) I_{[0, 1/n]}(x) - \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} I_{(1/n, \infty)}(x).$
(a) Show $f_{n}$ converges almost everywhere and identify the limit $f$.
My attempt:
We claim that $\{f_{n}(x)\} \rightarrow 
f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if } x < 0, \\
-\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}, & \text{if } x > 0.
\end{cases}$. Moreover, $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ diverges at $x=0$ (on a set of measure 0. Clearly when $x<0$, $f_{n}(x)=0$, and hence converges to $f(x)$. When $x=0$, we have $f_{n}(x)=n$, which diverges. In the case where $x>0$, fix $x$ and let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $N$ such that $x>\frac{1}{N}$.  Then $n\geq N$ implies $x>\frac{1}{n}$, so $f_{n}(x)= \frac{-1}{x^2+1}$, Hence, $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$. Thus, $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow \frac{-1}{x^2+1}$ almost everywhere.
Is this reasoning correct? And is it okay that $f(x)$ isn't defined at $x=0$?
Secondly, we are asked to determine if $f_{n}(x)$ converges in measure. I think no, for the following reasons:
When $x<0$, we have $m(\{x: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon\})$ = $m(\{x:0 \geq \epsilon\})=m(\emptyset)=0$. When $x=0$, we have $m(\{x: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon)=m(\{x:n-n^2x-f(0)|\geq \epsilon\}$. I believe this set that we are taking the measure of is trivially the empty set, since $f(0)$ is undefined, but I'm not totally sure this makes sense. But if it does, then again we have $m(\emptyset)=0$. So this holds. However, I believe the problem arises when $x>0$. We have $m(\{x:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}) = m(\{x: x\leq \frac{1}{n}\})$. But, this is $m(\infty)$, so I do not believe that $f_{n}$ converges in measure. Does my reasoning make sense? Thank you in advance! :)

Don't use MathJax to format text. To produce bold text, use markdown.

I do not see how that set is $[0,1/n]$.

Regarding the convergence in measure: note that if $x \in \Bbb R \setminus [0, 1/n]$, then $f_n(x) =f(x)$.
So, given any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$ {x \in  \Bbb R:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon} \subseteq [0,1/n] $$
So,
$$ m({x \in  \Bbb R:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon}) \leqslant m([0,1/n]) = 1/n$$
So $f_n$ converge in measure to $f$.
